# Select from one table different values and limit them

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I have one table :

```
first_column | last_column
--------------------------
text         | text
text         | text
text         | NO text
```

Now I want to select from this table with LIMIT 80 where `last_column` is "text" and LIMIT 80 WHERE `last_column` is "NO text"

My problem is that "NO text" can have only 79 rows.

Some help for one query please?

Comment: *`NO text` can have only 79 rows* how is this your problem? Can you explain please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to get 80 rows for both `text` and `NO text`, you can use `UNION ALL`. You can also order your data as per your requirement:

```
(SELECT first_column, last_column
FROM MyTable
WHERE last_column = 'text'
ORDER BY first_column
LIMIT 80)
UNION ALL
(SELECT first_column, last_column
FROM MyTable
WHERE last_column = 'NO text'
ORDER BY first_column
LIMIT 80);
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aee774/1)